# 'Critical security alert for your linked Google Account ' but I don't recognize the account

Tags: email, google, account-security

I received an email entitled : 'Critical security alert for your linked Google Account' .. The body says:

> Someone knows the password to your linked Google Account
>
> ----------@gmail.com
>
> Google has become aware that someone else knows your password, and
>   we've taken steps to protect your account. Please sign back into your
>   account now and choose a new password to secure your account.

I've removed the account name. I do not recognize this account so it should not be linked to my account. I did change my password immediately after receiving this email though it looks like it's saying that someone knows the unknown address' password.  I checked the headers on the email that I received and they indeed appear to be coming from Google and were not spoofed. The links in the email also go directly to Google's site for all links so the email seems legitimate.

In full disclosure, a trojan was run on my computer recently. At that time I did turn on 2FA for my gmail account and changed passwords on some of my saved google passwords. I am uncertain if this is related to the trojan.

Can a trojan pull my saved Google/Chrome password file? Is there a way to see what accounts my gmail may be linked to?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I can link my Google account to yours. I just need to add your email to my account as a linked account. No maliciousness required. I get them a lot because my Gmail address is so generic, people mistakenly use my address by mistake.

Can malware open your browser's password file? Yes.

Can you see who has added your email to their linked accounts? I do not believe so.

Comment: Thanks for this .. I also get lots of people using my email as theirs so hopefully that's the cause.

I _thought_ that someone would need to have your password to access your saved google passwords?